# CSS-only and layout friendly Reveal Focus from Fluent Design System

Tags: html, css, fluent-design

In the [Reveal focus docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal-focus) its:

[image]

But, as the docs

> Reveal focus increases the size of the focus visual, which might cause issues with your UI layout. In some cases, you'll want to customize the Reveal focus effect to optimize it for your app.

How would you approach creating the effect that does not affect the UI in the way described above?

My Reveal focus component:

1. Reveal glow is `box-shadow`
2. Primary focus visual is `outline`
3. Secondary focus visual is `border`
4. Background

but something seems off and I can't quite grasp it. Is it `box-shadow`, is it spacing (like `margin`, I don't set any as you can see), or is it yet something else? How would you fix it if you wanted it to look like on the gif below?

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 100px;
}
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 82px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
.x1 { width: 19%; }
.x2 { width: 38%; }

.reveal-focus {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
}

.reveal-focus:focus {
  outline-color: #61B250;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #61B250;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x2"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x2"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shadow is being placed above elements that appear before the focused one, but below elements after it. You need to add `position: relative` to all the elements, and `z-index: 1` to the focused one.

To make sure this doesn't interfere with any other stacking, apply `position: relative; z-index: 0` to the container. This ensures that it has its own stacking context.

The GIF you show appears to also have a slight animation effect, with the glow being more intense for just a moment before fading to normal. This can be achieved quite simply with `animation`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 100px;
}
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 82px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
.x1 { width: 19%; }
.x2 { width: 38%; }

.reveal-focus {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.reveal-focus:focus {
  border-color: #000;
  outline-color: #61B250;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #61B250;
  animation: glowfade 0.4s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes glowfade {
  from {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 6px #61B250;}
  to {box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #61B250;}
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x2"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x2"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
<a href="#" class="tile reveal-focus x1"></a>
```

Adjust values as desired.

Comment: Yes, I was definitely missing the animation. About adjusting the values - do you think, looking at the GIF, that there is some "right" proportions between `box shadow`, `border` and `outline`? Also, I think now that `.reveal-focus:focus` does not need the `border-color` to get it parents background color.